# Is it possible to ask Factory Girl what associations a given factory has?

Tags: ruby, unit-testing, factory-bot

[Factory Girl](https://github.com/thoughtbot/factory_girl) is incredibly useful for functional testing, but has one annoying property that makes it slightly harder to use in unit tests, where I don't want to rely on the test database. I often use `Factory.build` to create a factory that I can then pass around or assign to an `ActiveRecord.find` call using [flexmock](http://flexmock.rubyforge.org/):

```
require 'test_helper'
require 'flexmock'

class SomeMixinTest < ActiveSupport::TestCase
  include FlexMock::TestCase

  def setup
    @foo = Factory.build(:foo, :id => 123,
        :bar => Factory.build(:bar, :id => 456,
            :baz => Factory.build(:baz, :id => 789)
        )
    )

    flexmock Foo, :find => @foo
  end

  def test_find_by_reverse_id
    assert_equal @foo, Foo.find_by_reverse_id(321)
  end
end
```

This pattern is very nice, since it cares not about the presence of the database, and runs much faster than if the objects had to actually be persisted. However, it is a bit annoying to have to build the associated objects manually. If you don't, the associated objects **are** actually created in the database by the `build` call, as if you had used `create` instead.

```
assert_equal [], Foo.all
foo = Factory.build :foo  # build my associations too, please
assert_equal [], Foo.all  # look Ma, no mocks!
assert_equal [], Bar.all  # <=== ASSERTION FAILED
assert_equal [], Baz.all
```

This is non-intuitive to say the least, and causes an actual problem when I'm testing a few classes that need to play nicely with a mixin. I want to be able to do this:

```
  KLASSES_UNDER_TEST = [Foo, Bar, Baz]

  def test_find_by_reverse_id
    KLASSES_UNDER_TEST.each do |klass|
      objects = (123..456).map do |id|
        Factory.build klass.to_s.downcase.to_sym, :id => id
      end

      flexmock klass, :all => objects

      objects.each do |object|
        assert_equal object, klass.find_by_reverse_id(object.id.to_s.reverse), "#{klass} #{object.id}"
    end
  end
```

But this has the nasty side effect of creating 333 `Bar`s and 666 `Baz`es ("Baz" does sound kind of like a demon's nickname, so maybe that's fitting) in the database, making this test slower than molasses flowing uphill in the winter.

I'd like to create a helper method like this:

```
  def setup_mocks(klass)
    klass_sym = klass.to_s.downcase.to_sym
    objects = (123..456).map{|id|
      associated_objects = Hash[
        Factory.associations(klass_sym).map do |association|
          [ association, setup_mocks(association, 1) ]
        end
      ]

      Factory.build klass_sym, associated_objects
    end

    flexmock klass, :all => objects
    objects
  end
```

So, does anything like `Factory.associations` exist?

Answer (score 0):

I've not tested this, but looking at the source it seems that something like this should work:

```
FactoryGirl.find(:factory_name).associations
```